# How to play HTML5 video in webview in android?

Tags: java, android

How do I play HTML5 Video in Webview in android?

Answer (score 0):

Embed the video tag as below in yoru WebView

```
<video id="video" autobuffer width="320" height="240">
  <source src="movie.mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Set the event as below for `click`.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);
```

Though using `type="video/mp4"` is accepted HTML5 standard, Andorid browsers seem to mess up with it. So don't use it.